# Open OS/2 icons on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, images, os2

I have an OS/2 .ico file I need to open (and, if possible, edit). It is different from an MS-Windows .ico file, therefore I cannot open it the usual way.

How can I open these files on Windows or (preferably) Linux anyway?

Comment: I might give this a crack if I can find the time. Given the considerable rarity of an OS/2 system, maybe you could upload this specific icon file somewhere?

Comment: The specific icon is from the Firefox codebase. All brandings have one. I am working on an alternative branding and have replaced all the picture files, except this one. What bugs me is that they needed to create them, too. Find an icon in every subfoloder: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/7433abfef863/browser/branding

Comment: And just for the protocol: I know they should be all the same, I just wondered - and need to replace all if I replace any, of course...

Comment: If the Firefox folks have the icon, presumably they have the tools to fool around with it, or can point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

Try [PMView](http://www.pmview.com/), there is a 31-day evaluation. For running in Linux, check out this posting: http://www.pmview.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=134&st=0&p=1275&#entry1275.

Comment: Wish there was a native port. It's one of the best image viewers out there